# Characteristics of a monotonic function on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions, continuity

> Let $f:[a,b]$ be a monotonic function. Then
>
> 1. $f$ is continuous.
> 2. $f$ is discontinuous at most two points.
> 3. $f$ is discontinuous at finitely many points.
> 4. $f$ is discontinuous at most countable points.

Solution:

- $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$ is monotonic  and continuous.So,$(1)$ holds.
- $f:[-5,5]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=
  \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c}0;x<-1\\
  1;-1\leq x<0 \\ 
  2;0\leq x<1 \\ 
  3;x\geq1
  \end{array}
  \right. 
  $ is montonic and discontinuous at  three points.Hence,$(2)$ does not hold.
- $f:[0,1]\bigcap \mathbb Q^c\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$ is monotonic  and discontinuous at uncountabe points.So,$(3)$ & (4)does not holds.

Please check my solution!

Comment: You misunderstood the question. You are not asked examples of each. You are asked which of the alternatives holds.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what the question asks about. For instance, (1) isn't the statement "If $f$ is monotonic, then it _could_ be continuous" but rather "If $f$ is monotonic, then it _must necessarily_ be continuous". Also, your $f:[0,1]\bigcap \mathbb Q^c\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not discontinuous anywhere. Do not confuse "isn't defined" with "is discontinuous".

Comment: The items 2. and 4. are not English, are they?

Comment: @YvesDaoust:sorry,i don't get you?

Comment: They are not valid English sentences.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:I don't know about it,i just copied the problem from my problem sheet

Comment: Isn't English your mother tongue ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust:ofcourse english it is.I thought that you're asking  grammatical terms.

Comment: @postmortes: usually you say "in at most"; the last sentence requires a longer fix.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function

$$f(x):x\in\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]\to\frac xn,\\0\to0.$$

It is monotonic in $[0,1]$ but has countably many discontinuities, hence it invalidates 1., 2. and 3.

[image]

Comment: :How you've  thought about such function?As, you've also given example in support of (4) then how's your answer is different from my examples which i used  for discarding the options.It seems that your answer is not analytic one?

Comment: @postmortes What is wrong with this example of countable discontinuities ?

Comment: @postmortes: why do you need measure theory? The fact that monotone functions have only jump discontinuity and also the fact the jumps are all in one direction with their sum bounded is sufficient.

Comment: @postmortes: this answer nowhere tries to disprove the fact that monotone functions can have at most a countable number of discontinuities.